# ListView with conditional formatting doesn't work properly(using a ViewBinder)

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

**Auxiliary Problem**

Hi, could anyone please help me understand the behavior of `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.setViewValue`?

It seems that it is called more than once for each row in the `ListView`. Does the number of calls depend on the number of rows in the ListView? Or number of items in the cursor of `SimpleCursorAdapter`? Also, what are the significance of the parameters passed to the function?

### Main Problem

I'm having this strange problem while trying to create a simple `ListView` of `CheckedTextViews`. I wanted to reduce the opacity of the rows which are checked. The code I wrote worked, except that it will always reduce the opacity of one extra row.

Making the layout_height of the `ListView` to match_parent solved the issue for some cases. But the problem still persists when I open the keyboard for editing and the ListView somehow gets required.

---

Please find the codes here

Code to fill the items in `ListActivity`:

```
private void fillDataToList() {
    Cursor all_taskCursorCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllTask();
    startManagingCursor(all_taskCursorCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{TaskDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.task_title};

    SimpleCursorAdapter tasks = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.task_row, all_taskCursorCursor, from, to);

    tasks.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if(columnIndex == 1) {
                CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;

                String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TaskDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
                boolean checked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TaskDbAdapter.KEY_COMPLETED)) == 1 ? true : false; 

                ctv.setText(text);
                ctv.setChecked(checked); 

                if (checked == true) {
                    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.25f);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    ctv.setAnimation(animation); 

                    ctv.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    setListAdapter(tasks);
}
```

The layout of ListView -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/no_task"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for each row -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding one else condition to if (checked == true) part.

The final code looks like this -

```
if (checked == true) {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.25f);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    ctv.setAnimation(animation); 

    ctv.setPaintFlags(ctv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
} else {
    ctv.setPaintFlags(ctv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
}
```

Comment: This happens because the views in the ListView are reused.